# Why are Java native buffers that slow?

Tags: java, android, performance, algorithm, image-processing

I was trying to optimize a simple region growing algorithm I am running on an Android device. Originally I used an `ArrayList` to save the points that belong to one region. Each point was described by a `Point` instance, which needed to be instantiated for every point. It took the algorithm **about 15 seconds** to find all regions within an image with about 1 megapixels.

The `Point` class was as simple as:

```
class Point
{
    public int x, y;
}
```

I thought I could reduce the computation time by reducing the number of `Point` instantiations. So I replaced the point lists by a `Region` class, that utilizes native buffers for point enlisting:

```
private int capacity;
private int pointsCount = 0;

private ByteBuffer buffer;
private IntBuffer intBufferView;
```

The computation of the required byte buffer size, based on the number of points:

```
private static int getByteBufferSize( int capacity )
{
    // 4 bytes per integer and 2 integers per point
    return capacity * 4 * 2;
}
```

The initial capacity I chose as 100, but I also tried setting it to 10, which is the initial capacity of `ArrayList`, and I tried setting it to the size of the largest region in my testing image:

```
public Region()
{
    this.capacity = 100;
    this.buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect( getByteBufferSize( 100 ) );
    this.intBufferView = buffer.asIntBuffer();
}
```

For adding points to the region I used this method:

```
public void add( final Point point )
{
    if( pointsCount >= capacity )
    {
        grow();
    }

    final int offset = 2 * pointsCount;
    intBufferView.put( offset + 0, point.x );
    intBufferView.put( offset + 1, point.y );
    ++pointsCount;
}
```

And for reading a certain point, identified by an index, this method:

```
public void fetchPoint( Point p, int pointIndex )
{
    final int offset = 2 * pointIndex;
    p.x = intBufferView.get( offset + 0 );
    p.y = intBufferView.get( offset + 1 );
}
```

I implemented the growth policy equal to the policy that is used by `ArrayList`:

```
private void grow()
{
    capacity = ( capacity * 3 ) / 2 + 1;
    final int bufferSize = getByteBufferSize( capacity );
    final ByteBuffer newBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect( bufferSize );
    newBuffer.put( buffer );
    newBuffer.rewind();
    buffer = newBuffer;
    intBufferView = buffer.asIntBuffer();
}
```

However, with this optimization the region growing algorithm takes **about 33 seconds to finish on the very same image.** This is a performance drop I cannot explain. Is it my implementation, the whole idea, or what is the problem here?

Comment: I worked with ByteBuffer before and it does not take anywhere close to milliseconds (or even maybe nearly seconds as in your case) to operate. Check your own algorithms - 99.99% of time the problem will be somewhere there and in 99.99% of time it will be in some code that you did **not** post here.

Comment: I bet you that > 90% of the time consumed (in the code shown) is spent in grow(). Allocating and copying data is the expensive part.

Comment: @theV0ID Perhaps because of the conclusive, rant-in-disguise tone of the question? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frankly, I think it is the whole idea that is wrong.  The `Buffer` classes are optimized for a different user-case to yours; i.e. transferring data to and from I/O devices (in the broad sense.

If you want better (than current) performance, replace the `Buffer` with an `int[]`.  I predict that you will see a smaller performance drop (compared with the `ArrayList<Point>` version), but you will still see a drop.  That is the penalty you pay for the memory saving.

Comment: Agree, more often that not it's the misuse that causes the problems, not the actual system and/or standard functionality.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. One Question left. You predicted a performance drop with `int[]` compared to `ArrayList<Point>`, right? I tried that, and it gave me a performance boost: The whole segmentation takes **about 7-8 seconds** now. I'm wondering whether it is possible to achieve even better performance through a JNI implementation of `Region`.

Comment: Predictions are like that ... and I'm a pessimist.

Comment: The only way JNI will give you better performance is if you save more by doing the region calculations in native code than you lose in the Java <-> JNI <-> native call overheads.

Comment: This answer is rather wrong. Direct buffers are pretty fast on a server JVM and get used when you need unmanaged memory (no GC there)  and better *memory locality* in order to get consistent very low latency, s. e.g. [HugeCollections](https://github.com/peter-lawrey/HugeCollections). An Android, the efficiency may differ. I'd bet that the `int[]` is faster because of memory locality. So I'd say: good idea, wrong platform.

Comment: @maartinus - You are talking about a different use-case.  In this case, I would expect the locality properties of an `int[]` and an `IntBuffer` to be identical.  Irrespective of the platform.  (I believe that you are thinking of the case where you use a mapped buffer instead of a collection of objects.  That's NOT what is happening here ...)